# Custom NSTextFieldCell for NSOutlineView

Tags: cocoa, drawing, nsoutlineview, nstextfieldcell, pxsourcelist

I am wondering how to draw a `NSTextFieldCell` like the one in NetNewsWire.

I have already subclassed a `NSTextFieldCell` for the group cell and specified it in my `PXSourceList's` `dataCellForItem`.

The source list is cell based.

I just don't know how to draw the cells.

[image: NetNewsWire]

Comment: Which cells are you trying to draw?  The cells with the arrows pointing at them or the cells that have an orange gradient background?

Comment: The cells with the arrows pointing at them.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Apple sample "SourceView", that contains a subclass of NSTextFieldCell called ImageAndTextCell that does what you want.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SourceView/Introduction/Intro.html

Though if it were me, I'd change to using a view based OutlineView and use the built in NSTableCellView which already supports an imageView.

Comment: Yeah I figured it out but I am still pondering over the group cell (the one with "On my Mac").